# Dell Precision 7730 OEM Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, dell, bios, nomodeset, oem

I'm struggling with installing Ubuntu. The only way I could run Ubuntu was with `nomodeset` but nothing worked graphically.

Before that I had made a very successful install with RAID config on, but due to a lot of crap I needed to install both Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I turned off RAID (also better in Windows 10) and the Ubuntu installer wasn't even loading. I had a lot of problems, and I couldn't start an installation without using `nomodeset`.

I had the same USB stick. When it succeeded it was on mbr in Rufus, (with Ubuntu 18.04), but Ubuntu 20.04 didn't seem to work. Is there a way I can obtain the OEM image? I called Dell before, but they refused to help.

Answer (score 0):

You crapped out with the Dell OEM image request, but you mentioned that you successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 with Rufus. You will need to install Windows 10 before installing Ubuntu and then select UEFI mode in Rufus in order to be compatible with Windows 10. Getting the Ubuntu installer to work in UEFI mode on your Dell Precision 7730 is your biggest problem as I see it. Installing Ubuntu 18.04 worked before, so try installing Ubuntu 18.04 again and immediately upgrading it to Ubuntu 20.04.